# How to intercept promise request?

Tags: javascript, q

I'm using q promises, and I want to show the spinners when promise starts. Currently I'm doing this way:

```
getPromise().then(function() { spinner.hide() })
```

and in the `getPromise()` fn, I'm showing up the spinner, so `getPromise` looks like:

```
function getPromise()
{
    spinner.show()
}
```

But is there any way to intercept the `then` block in q, so that I can add the `spinner.show` to that intercept?

Comment: You don't "intercept" then blocks in any promises.  You chain your own `.then()` handler onto a promise and your handler will be called when the promise fulfills.

Comment: @JaromandaX: `.then(…)` is invoked immediately, the `function() { … })` callback that was passed to it will be invoked only on fulfillment

Comment: @batman: I don't understand what you want. Your current way seems fine. How would you expect an "interception" to look like? Regardless of what exactly it is doing, how do you want to invoke it?

Comment: @Bergi: Something similar to what ajax gives like `ajaxStart`.

Comment: @batman: You mean jQuery? Surely you can do that with `getPromise` as well. Just insert an `if (typeof getPromise.start == "function") getPromise.start();` where you currently have that `spinner.show`, and then you can freely configure your method by e.g. doing `getPromise.start = function() { spinner.show(); };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are over-thinking it

```
var spinOnPromise = function(p) {
  spinner.show()
  p.finally(function() {
    spinner.hide()
  });
  return p;
}
```

Pass in the promise, and the spinner will go as long as the promise is pending.

**Edit:** you *could* do this:

```
var spinOnPromise = function(p) {
  spinner.show()
  return p.finally(function() {
    return spinner.hide()
  });
}
```

If you do this this, the difference is, if `spinner.hide()` returns a promise (call it `p1`), the promise returned from `spinOnPromise()` will not be resolved until `p1` is resolved, but it will resolve to the same value as `p`.  See [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback) for details.

You could do this, but I don't see offhand why you would.

Comment: You should return the result of the `finally()` call though, not the original `p`romise, otherwise errors will bubble to unexpected paths.

Comment: @Bergi: Something like this: `p.finally(function(data) {
    spinner.hide(); return data;
  });` ? Thanks.

Comment: No, I didn't mean returning from the callback, I meant to `return p.finally(…)` itself.